# Time complexity of block-encoded matrices

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, block-encoding

A lot of modern quantum computation has this idea of "block-encoding" matrices; loosely, this is encoding a non-unitary matrix into the top left corner of a larger unitary matrix. This technique is referenced a lot, but I don't see how it can be implemented with quantum circuits.

Suppose we were given an arbitrary matrix, $C$. This matrix can be non-unitary and non-square. As a result, it cannot be represented by a quantum circuit. How is it possible that we can "block-encode" this into a quantum circuit (a universal gate set acted on by tensor product operations) in a reasonable amount of steps?

Mathematically, the technique makes sense when the spectral norm is less than $1$. But I don't see how it makes sense in practice and complexity-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $C$ you block-encode can be non-unitary but must be square. There are many techniques for embedding $C$ into a unitary matrix. Examples of explicit quantum circuits are provided in this very recent paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.10236

Another interesting paper on this subject is: https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.02859

Comment: Actually, the second reference you mentioned shows in Section II.D that we can also block encode rectangular matrices.

Answer (score 1):

From [Lecture Notes on Quantum Algorithms for Scientific Computation](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2201.08309) by Lin:

> Of course, if $A$ is a dense matrix without obvious structures, any input model will be very expensive (e.g. exponential in $n$) to implement. Therefore a commonly assumed input model is $s$-sparse, i.e., there are at most $s$ nonzero entries in each row / column of the matrix. Furthermore, we have an efficient procedure to get access to the location, as well as the value of the nonzero entries. This in
> general can again be a difficult task given that the number of nonzero entries can still be exponential in $n$ for a sparse matrix. Some dense matrices may also be efficiently block encoded on quantum computers.